# can't upload multiple images iin zend freamework on server

Tags: php, zend-framework

i have a problem with upload mutilply files using zend framework on server

actually my code works correctly on localhost but on remote server it gives me application error message

my host is ipage.com

```
$upload = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
$upload->setDestination('projects\\'.$_pId);
// $_pid is my project folder where all files related to it uploded
$files = $upload->getFileInfo();
$i = 1;$g = 1;
foreach ($files as $file => $info)
{
    // i have three kinds of images
    // innerfinishingphotos_ images which can be more than 1 file eg :innerfinishingphotos_1, innerfinishingphotos_2, innerfinishingphotos_3.
    // outerfinishingphotos_ images which can be more than 1 file eg :outerfinishingphotos_1, outerfinishingphotos_2, outerfinishingphotos_3.
    // _main_photo image an image.

    // here i made if statements to determine which file came from which input file 

    if( $info == $files["innerfinishingphotos_".$i] && $info["name"] ==  $files["innerfinishingphotos_".$i]["name"] && !empty( $info["name"] ) )
    {
        $filename = "inner_finishing".$_pId.uniqid().$files["innerfinishingphotos_".$i]["name"];
        $upload->addFilter('Rename', $filename, $files["innerfinishingphotos_".$i]);
        $photodata =  Array ("project_id"=> $_pId, "photo_link"=> "/projects/".$_pId."/".$filename, "photo_name"=> "inner_finishing");
        $projectModel->addInProjectGalary($photodata);
        $i++;
    }
    else if( $info == $files["outerfinishingphotos_".$g] && $info["name"] == $files["outerfinishingphotos_".$g]["name"] &&!empty( $info["name"] ) )
    {
        $filename = "outer_finishing".$_pId.uniqid().$files["outerfinishingphotos_".$g]["name"];
            $upload->addFilter('Rename', $filename, $files["outerfinishingphotos_".$g]);
            $photodata =  Array ("project_id"=> $_pId, "photo_link"=> "/projects/".$_pId."/".$filename, "photo_name"=> "outer_finishing");
            $projectModel->addInProjectGalary($photodata);
            $g++;
    }
    else if ($info == $files["_main_photo"] && !empty( $info["name"] ))
    {
        $filename = "main_photo".$_pId.uniqid().$files["_main_photo"]["name"];
            $upload->addFilter('Rename', $filename, $files["_main_photo"]);
            $photodata =  Array ("project_id"=> $_pId, "photo_link"=> "/projects/".$_pId."/".$filename, "photo_name"=> "project_photo");
            $projectModel->addInProjectGalary($photodata);  
    }

    //then i receive the image
    if($upload->isValid($file))
    {
        try {
            $upload->receive($file);  
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                echo "upload exteption";
            }   
    }
}
```

i tested this code and i works correctly on localhost and all images uploaded and their data entered my database

but on my remote host 'ipage.com' not work.

please guys help me

Comment: What error message do you get? 'Application error' is just the user friendly message shown to the user, check the error logs for the actual error message.

Comment: how can i get the actual error? where error logs?

Comment: i can't determine what causes the problem .

Comment: It will be in the main Apache error log by default (if you are using Apache). Try /var/log/apache2/error.log. Otherwise contact your host.

Comment: after contacting with my host customer services they told me that the problem in the application not on the server, i can't find the problem in my code, can any one helps me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after many hours trying, i solved the problem , it wase in this line

```
$upload->setDestination('projects\\'.$_pId);
```

changing it to

```
$upload->setDestination('projects/'.$_pId);
```

thank you mr. Tim Fountain